# Installing Anaconda and the modules not working

Tags: python, anaconda, statsmodels

I have just installed Anaconda and then when I tried to use Idle to use the module statsmodels it tells me it doesn't exist:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels'
```

If I then try installing the module using pip it tells me its there.

I have also tried uninstalling Anaconda and installing the modules separately but the connection times out. [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy4l3.jpg)

I am at work so could this be due to the pip module being unable to get through the proxy?

If that is the case why did Anaconda not seem to work either?

Comment: Open up a command prompt and start the Python interpreter from there and import statsmodel. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I am still unable to get the libraries working on Idle. But I have started using Spyder, which came with Anaconda and all the libraries are working there.

This is fine for my purposes. Though it would be good to know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired installing the individual packages via pip? I am running into the same problem. It was working for some, not for others....

Comment: Hey Evan, thanks that's what I've now done installing the packages separately for when I want to use them on Idle. But I just think that it defeats my initial purpose of installing Anaconda, a quick easy way to install a whole lot of packages for scientific computing. But I do think that the Spyder interface is pretty good, so at least I got something out of it.

Comment: I was having the same issues but eventually I figured it out. I removed all Python version I had on my computer, removed Anaconda and all associated files. I then reinstalled the Anaconda and Python package from the anaconda website. During the install, however, I added Anaconda to PATH. It says not to but I did and it has been working ever since. I have not had any time importing libraries and everything else seems to be working fine too. I hope this helps!